# Mutilevel include in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I want to have MULTILEVEL include in my linq statment, something like

```
var a = departments.include(u=>u.Customers)
                   .include(u=>u.Customers.Include(u=>u.Orders);
```

How should i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You of course can use lambda expression but you must use special format:

```
var a = departments.Include(d => d.Customers.Select(c => c.Orders));
```

Comment: What the hell, i already accept the answer of jeroenh but i never like static string, ur answer is just awesome. BIG THANKS

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
departments.Include("Customers.Orders");
```

Obviously you can't use a lambda expression anymore.

cf. documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: We can use lambda operator with Include http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/

Answer (score 2):

[Jeroenh was quicker, but lambda is ok i think...]

Shouldnt be a problem. For entity framework without proxies we use:

```
var a=departments.Include("Customers.Orders").Single(dept => dept.Customers.Id == id);
```

/Victor

Answer (score 0):

You could specify which nested objects to be retrieved when the query is being executed by using the [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx) method.