# Linq Exception The expression must be a MemberExpression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, iqueryable

i am working on a linq query and try to include entities upto multi level as per suggested in [Mutilevel include in C# Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742581/mutilevel-include-in-c-sharp-linq).

So i write down a query like

```
 query.Include(u => u.Stops.Select(d => d.Address).Select(c => c.City));
```

where query is

```
IQueryable<SomeEntity> query
```

and i get the exception

> The expression must be a MemberExpression

Screenshot for my entities is [image]
Kindly help, Thanks

Comment: Show your `SomeEntity`, `Stop` and `Address` entities. It is not clear where those navigation properties belong.

Comment: Check the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx. Seems you need to nest the `Select()`s, not chain them. There's even an example for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ladislav, i've upload the screenshot for my entities, kindly verify

Comment: Inerdial, thanks for the link that is really very interesting and the last example somehow links with my issue, but the only problem is nested Select works if your navigation property is a collection, but this is not my case and in second last example, i am geting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

This overload (extension?) of `Include` does not support inclusion through method chains. It does, however, support nesting of inclusion expressions:

```
query.Include(u => u.Stops.Select(d => d.Address.City));

// this would work too:
categories.Include(u => u.SubCategories.Select(c => c.Items.Select(i => i.Manufacturer)));
// equals
categories.Include("SubCategories.Items.Manufacturer");
```

The `Select` part is only for accessing members of collection type property items.